# How to run a single test in npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, grep, mocha.js, chai

I have an acceptance test directory like

`tests/test_a.js`

`tests/test_b.js`

I'm trying to run a single test using `npm test -- test_a.js` but it doesn't seem to respect the fact that it's one file, it just runs everything in the directory.

I've also tried grep commands:

`npm test -- --grep '@test_a'`

but it also just runs the entire suite.

Any ideas?